# Create date by components in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Hello i have a problem: I try to create date by components but it's give me wrong hours..
For example, I want to have  2022-04-24 00:00:00
Here the code

```
func createDate(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int, hour: Int, minutes: Int)->Date {
   let calendar = Calendar.current

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.year = year
    dateComponents.month = month
    dateComponents.day = day
    dateComponents.hour = hour
    dateComponents.minute = minute

   let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
   return date
}

let date = createDate(year: 2022, month: 4, day: 24, hour: 0, minute: 0) // return 2022-04-23 22:00:00 +0000

let date2 = createDate(year: 2022, month: 4, day: 24, hour: 9, minute: 0) // return 2022-04-24 7:00:00 +0000
```

I have 2 hours late.
I'm in France, i set my virtual device in France region.
Do you know where is the error ?

Comment: Your date is correct. By default it uses the current timezone (from the user’s device). If you need to print the date use `date.description(with: .current)`. Only use UTC if you don’t want the user current timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "GMT" timezone, such as:

```
 dateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")
```

Comment: No don't works :/

Comment: sorry, try `dateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")`. Updated my answer.